# Formatação de saída de dados

Tags: java

Então galera, estava "futucando" no java, porém me surgiu uma dúvida. Como eu faço para formatar um número que esta num método?

Por exemplo:

Trecho de código:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,brand+ "Saldo atual de " +cliente1.getID()+" :"
+ "\n"+cliente1.getBalance());
```

Esse código imprime no formato 0000.0 porém eu queria tirar essa última casa decimal, já tentei usar o **%.4f** e o **%.4d**, mas não deu certo!

Como faço para tirar esse **.0** da exibição?

Obs.: o método `getBalance` é um método comum de um double privado.

Comment: Você quer simplesmente remover o decimal ou quer arredondar também?

Comment: Tente desta forma: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Valor: %.0f", valor));`

Comment: Diego, eu quero apenas tirar, e Dener, não foi, pois quando coloca essa vírgula ele entende que é um parâmetro a mais, e não uma concatenação

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,brand+ "Saldo atual de " +cliente1.getID()+" :"
+ "\n"+((int)cliente1.getBalance()));`

Comment: A vírgula para é indica o segundo parâmetro do método format, com ele vc consegue formatar as strings usando essas expressões, isso não é uma concatenação.

Comment: Veja se funciona usando a classe DecimalFormat: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Valor: " + new DecimalFormat("####").format(valor));`

Comment: Por algum motivo o compilador pegar seus 4 zeros a esquerda e transforma em 1 zero dando a saída: `0`

Comment: Por favor, define exatamente as regras de saída. O que acontece se as casas decimais não forem zero? Você quer oculta-las sempre ou apenas se forem zeros?

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver trabalhando com quatro zeros a esquerda, pode usar a seguinte expressão: `%04.0f` ela indica que o lado esquerdo da vírgula deve ser preenchido com quatro zeros e o lado direito não deve conter números, ou seja nenhuma parte decimal.

Veja o exemplo:

```
double valor = 0000.0;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Valor: %04.0f", valor));
```

Saída:

> Valor: 0000

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/a/275715/5429980